# How should we set the number of the neurons in the hidden layer in neural network?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, neural-network

In neural network theory - setting up the size of hidden layers seems to be a really important issue. Is there any criteria how to choose the number of neurons in a hidden layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - this is a really important issue. Basically there are two ways to do that:

1. **Try different topologies and choose best:** due to the fact that number of neurons and layers are a discrete parameters you cannot differentiate your loss function with respect to this parameters in order to use a gradient descent methods. So the easiest way is to simply set up different topologies and compare them using either cross-validation or division of your training set to - training / testing / validating parts. You can also use a **grid / random search** schemas to do that. Libraries like `scikit-learn` have appropriate modules for that.
2. **Dropout:** the training framework called dropout could also help. In this case you are setting up relatively big number of nodes in your layers and trying to adjust a dropout parameter for each layer. In this scenario - e.g. assuming that you will have a two-layer network with `100` nodes in your hidden layer with `dropout_parameter = 0.6` you are learning the mixture of models - where every model is a neural network with size `40` (approximately `60` nodes are *turned off*). This might be also considered as figuring out the best topology for your task.

Answer (score 1):

There are also a few other algorithms for creating and pruning hidden layer neurons on the fly. The one I'm most familiar with is Cascade Correlation, which gets pretty good performance for many applications, despite the fact that the hidden layer starts with a single neuron and adds others as needed.

For further reading see:

The original paper by Scott E. Fahlman and Christian Lebiere, [The Cascade-
Correlation Learning Architectur](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/207-the-cascade-correlation-learning-architecture.pdf)e.

• Gábor Balázs' [Cascade Correlation Neural Networks: A Survey.](http://papersdb.cs.ualberta.ca/~papersdb/uploaded_files/1033/additional_ccnnsurvey2009.pdf)

• Lutz Precehelt's [Investigation of the CasCor Family of Learning Algorithms Investigation of the CasCor Family of Learning Algorithms](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/neurnetw97.pdf).

There are many other such algorithms for dynamically constructing the hidden layer, which can be found scattered across the Internet in various .pdf research papers. Some sleuthing may be worthwhile to avoid reinventing the wheel and may turn up just the right method for the problem you're trying to solve. Neural net research is spread out across many varied disciplines so there's no telling what else is out there; keeping track of all the new algorithms is a daunting prospect. I hope that helps though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the number of neurons in hidden layer in such a way that it shouldn't be more than # of your training example. There are no thumb rule for number of neurons.
Ex: If you are using MINIST Dataset then you might have ~ 78K training example. So make sure that combination of Neural Network (784-30-10) = 784*30 + 30*10 which are less than training examples. but if you use like (784-100-10) then it exceeds the # of training example and highly probable to over-fit.
In short, make sure you are not over-fitting and hence you have good chances to get good result.